Is the Google Assistant SDK deprecated?/How to make API calls to Google Assistant?
I've gotten confused by the terminology of some of Google's products. "Conversational Actions" has been deprecated. Does that mean the entire Google Assistant SDK is deprecated?
https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview
Is there any way to make api calls to Google Assistant? I'd love to be able for my program to be able to perform Google related actions, like setting reminders, asking about the weather, ect. Python preferred but anything that works would be great.
Basically, I want to be able to make api calls to Google Assistant, as demonstrated by this sample:
https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-nodejs
but following the steps gets confusing because Google has changed some things and I can't register a device model. Is this example, or something like it, still possible?
